# Bypassing SQL Character Blacklist Filtering

Tags: security, sql-injection, sql-server-2000

I am working on a cyber security course containing a challenge on a SQL Server 2000 host.

I have leaked an `asp` file containing the source for the login page that contains a hardcoded query that takes the username and password from the user and proceeds to query the db...

`sSql = "SELECT * FROM Users where user_name='" & username & "' and user_password='"&password&"'"`

Before this is executed the user input is filtered with a loop over a the below method removing...

```
' " - & % / \ | > 

replace(myString, "&", "")
```

What I am trying to do is to escape the string containing the user or password, break the developing query and interrupt it with my own, then comment out the remainder to keep it 'valid'. In order to evade the blacklist I am trying to pass a `SUBSTRING` that will decode a series of hex characters into a valid nested query.

I have tested both parts in a sandbox VB script to check handling the encoded string and run the string in an online MSSQL emulator [here](https://rextester.com/live/LRPBOY65192) and it decode the query fine.

NOTE: Emulator is `Sql Server 2014 Express Edition` not 2K. Couldn't find one for 2K

I hope that makes sense!

Here is what I am trying to pass and what each character is trying to achieve...

Encoded Query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(60), SUBSTRING(0x22273B2053454C454354202A2066726F6D207573657273205748455245206E616D65203D2061646D696E3B202D2D20, 1, 96))
```

Translates to (with trailing space):

```
"'; SELECT * from users WHERE name = admin; --
```

What I am envisioning is that the below overall query is formed AFTER the `SUBSTRING` is processed:
`sSql = "SELECT * FROM Users where user_name='""'; SELECT * from users WHERE name = admin; --  & username & "' and user_password='"&password&"'"`

My hope is that leading double and single quote formation on my malicious request will break the string and the subsequent semicolon will end the request without causing an exception, then leading to the server processing my query and dropping the unnecessary remainder.

My question then, is is this approach valid from the perspective of SQL Server 2000? or are my assumptions on how the server is receiving and processing the query incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the way it is processed won't allow you to attack in this way.  With your payload the string will end up being:

```
SELECT * FROM Users where user_name='SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(60), SUBSTRING(0x2...0, 1, 96))' and user_password='"&password&"'
```

So the SELECT that you are trying to get executed will be in single quotes and never interpreted as code.

The key to this may be that you have two injections - try passing in a "\" into the first injection to escape the last quote and then use both injections to exploit it.

Comment: It's probably not exploitable then as `\` is filtered out of the user input before query is built and processed

Comment: @3therk1ll - My point in the last paragraph was that you don't need to pass a quote in this case to create an exploit - you can use the "\" to escape the second quote of the first string.  The first quote of the second string then closes that quote, and you can use the second string to inject code.